# Do I really need to "run as administrator" when executing an external commandline tool from my app?

Tags: windows, installation, uac

I created an application and an installation package with VS2010 setup project.
For a certain function within the application I execute an external commandline-tool (.exe) which is installed to the same folder as the application.

The application starts without any problems after the installation. I start it with no admin privileges. But it won't execute the external commandline tool. It works when I start the application with the flag "run as administrator".

Is there a way that this works without checking the "run as administrator"-flag?

Comment: If external tool requires admin privileges then UAC window is unavoidable. Only question is what and when will cause it to be displayed.

Comment: The UAC window doesn't even appear when the external tool is called. Since it is not executed it causes a crash of the application. I'll try to figure out why the external tool needs admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the external tool needs admin rights then you have no choice. You will need to run it elevated.

You can do that programmatically though. You don't need to set the compatibility options of the executable file to check the *Run as administrator* option. What you need to do is start the process by calling `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` and pass `"runas"` as the verb.